# Jenkins integration with Auth0

Tags: jenkins, saml, auth0

I posted the question already on the jenkins saml github repo, however not sure where is the exact cause of issue - https://github.com/connectifier/jenkins-saml-plugin/issues/9.
Any help is appreciated

## Auth0 Configuraiton

1. Created an app "Jenkins"
2. Under Jenkins app > Settings, the field "Allowed Callback URLs = http://52.34.126.192:8080/securityRealm/finishLogin" (I am using AWS , so that ip might change)
3. Scroll down by clicking "Advanced Settings" . Under Endpoints > SAML, copied the URL "SAML metadata URL" and pasted in browser. It downloaded an XML file . We will use this later on jenkins side
4. Had an Auth0 user "abc@xyz.com" with connection "username-password-Authentication" database

I expect that after integration , I should be able to login to Jenkins with "abc@xyz.com"

## Jenkins Config

1. Installed SAML plugin -https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SAML+Plugin
2. Enabled global security , then SAML , pasted the above XML file (step 3 above) into field "IdP MetaData", selected "Role based strategy" radio and hit save

[image]

3. No effect will be observed now as it is mentioned in SAML plugin that Anonymous has to be disabled before seeing changes.
4. Go to Manage and Assign roles, and then uncheck any box for anonymous (since if Anonymous is enabled, then auth will be bypassed)
5. As soon as you hit save, you will be redirected to the Auth0 Login page (you can customize the login page on auth0, for now I went with defaults)
6. Now I login with the Auth0 user that I created in Auth0 config

I get the error as below

[image]

## LOGS

On the Auth0 side, the logs say that the user successfully logged in

[image]

Any help or thoughts are highly appreciated. Since Auth0 login says successful, I am posting this here, instead of Auth0 bugs

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem in a local Jenkins server but couldn't. Here's what I did differently: (a) in Jenkins Global Security, disabled `Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits`. (b) in the `Addons` tab of my `Jenkins` app in Auth0, I enabled the **SAML2 web app** Addon

Comment: So were you able to use Auth0 for Jenkins authentication. Was that your overall goal ?

Comment: So I tried with the options you mentioned above. Still run into same issue. Were you able to successfully authenticate your jenkins via Auth0 ?

Answer (score 5):

This error seems to occur, when you do not explicitly set the `audience` setting in the auth0 SAML2 AddOn to the callback URL.

Setting it explicitly fixed the issue for me.

[image: Screenshot]

My guess: it is somehow related to the fact that the plugin uses a rather dated version of the pac4j libraries.

Comment: Thank you, after following the above instruction. Jenkins is getting authenticated via auth0 users with anonymous role. Did you try creating roles and assigning them to users in "Manage and Assign roles" section of  Jenkins ? I tried doing that, however the users always get mapped to whatever role Anonymous has

Comment: No, haven't tried this yet, I only did a proof of concept setup, but I will soon. Unfortunately something seems wrong with my account and I'm waiting for auth0 team to resolve the problem.